# error in printf() method

Tags: java, printf

I need help to fix my code. I don't know where is the problem, but it seems in `printf` the compiler give me error when I run this code. Why?

```
Employee  emp1 = new Employee();
emp1.setFname("Kim");
emp1.setLname("Yee");
emp1.setID(101);
emp1.setSalary(40000);

Employee  emp2 = new Employee();
emp2.setFname("Lana");
emp2.setLname("Yum");
emp2.setID(102);
emp2.setSalary(55.000);

Employee  emp3 = new Employee();
emp3.setFname("Alex");
emp3.setLname("Jhone");
emp3.setID(103);
emp3.setSalary(55.500);

Employee  emp4 = new Employee();
emp4.setFname("joe");
emp4.setLname("mac");
emp4.setID(104);
emp4.setSalary(74.000);

System.out.println("Employee Name \t Employee ID \t Employee salary");  

System.out.printf("%s %s\t%d\t$%f\n", emp1.getFname() + "" + emp1.getLname(), emp1.getID(), emp1.getSalary());
System.out.printf("%s %s\t%d\t$%f\n", emp2.getFname() + "" + emp2.getLname(), emp2.getID(), emp2.getSalary());
System.out.printf("%s %s\t%d\t$%f\n", emp3.getFname() + "" + emp3.getLname(), emp3.getID(), emp3.getSalary());
System.out.printf("%s %s\t%d\t$%f\n", emp4.getFname() + "" + emp4.getLname(), emp4.getID(), emp4.getSalary());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add more details (for example, the error message(s) you're getting) to your question; as it stands, it risks being put on hold.

Comment: Please don't use tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nishant Shreshth and @hexafraction are right. However, you have not thought the problem through. Any time you have repetitious code like this, you're missing an opportunity. Why not write a method on `Employee` to return the full name of the employee? You will certainly find more places to use that in a real program.

```
public String getFullName() {
    return fname + " " + lname;
}
```

One should avoid drudgery.  Remember Larry Wall's three virtues of programming: hubris, impatience, and laziness. You should do extra work now so you can be lazy later.

Now, a person's first and last names are more associated with each other than with his id and salary. Also, people have names even if they aren't employees. So, you should really create a `Name` class and use it in `Employee` (or `Person`, or `Student`, or `Customer`...) instead of `fname` and `lname`.  You can then make changes to it when requirements change.  How difficult would it be to add *middleInitial* to all the classes that keep name components? What of *title*? What of *suffix*?  You may not have the requirement to do that now, but it's a matter of judgement how much to prepare for the future.

If you become a Java programmer, you may also want to have your class implement `java.util.Formattable`. That is an advanced topic.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.printf("%s %s\t%d\t$%f\n", emp1.getFname()+""+emp1.getLname(), emp1.getID(),emp1.getSalary());
```

This is the culprit:

```
emp1.getFname()+""+emp1.getLname()
```

That expression right above is ONE string. Use:

```
System.out.printf("%s\t%d\t$%f\n", emp1.getFname()+""+emp1.getLname(), emp1.getID(),emp1.getSalary());
```

or

```
System.out.printf("%s %s\t%d\t$%f\n", emp1.getFname(), emp1.getLname(), emp1.getID(),emp1.getSalary());
```

so you have a matching number of parameters and format specifiers in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

I think `+""+` should be just a `,`